# Why isn't Android L listed in the SDK Manager?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-cardview

I want to try CardView that is available on Android L. But Android L isn't listed in the SDK Manager.

[image]

I use android studio. This is the screenshot.
[image]

Some said that I need to upgrade my JDK to 7.0. My JDK is already 7.0.

[image]

What should I do? I use Fedora by the way.

Comment: There is Levels 21 and 22 are L

Comment: Look here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Comment: I changed the minimum sdk to 21 and it still the same. My android studio ask me to download android l but I can't download it

Comment: choose itembox and click install button in bottom right corner

Comment: Select all the checkboxes and install. It will take a **looooooooooooong** time.

Comment: And btw: *"Some said that I need to upgrade my JDK to 7.0"* Nonsense. 1.6 is enough.

Comment: Android L = Android Lollipop (5.x), is not? But Android L is a SDK which released preview to test its bugs, and available before Android Lollipop. So, after Google releases Android Lollipop, Android L might be removed from repository because the bug already detected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Android L` was the identifier for the 5.0 preview SDK, which is no longer available. The release version is `Android 5.0.1 (API 21)`.

Comment: Thank you. What I need to do is change compileSdkVersion, minSdkVersion, and targetSdkVersion on app/build.gradle to 21